wifi problem android 14 with to trying conect with charles proxy
I am trying to get a Charles Log from an android device, and it is not working. The android device's browser will not connect to the internet after I set up the Wifi with the Proxy. I have listed the steps I did to set up Charles Proxy on my computer and configure the android device to use charles proxy.
msg error: Get the error message “err_proxy_connection_failed” or "err_connection_timed_out". I am grateful for any help.
I'm grateful for any help.

Make sure Charles is not blocked by a firewall on your PC. Also make sure to use the correct IP of your PC and that network communication between PC and Android is possible (not blocked by the Wifi router).
